# select entries that has one word

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called post in which it has a column called title. I wanted to select all post which only have 1 word as the title. So for example 'cat' , 'dog' . There are posts which has more than one more such as 'cat and dog are not good', this I don't want to select. Only post with one word title only. How can I do so with mysql ?

Comment: anything with one word has no spaces, does thhat help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE title NOT LIKE '% %'
```

Chooses rows where titles have no spaces.

**EDIT:**

> If a single word with a space in the end like `cat`, then?

Then you smack your users with a tunafish for making silly inputs, and also your programmers for not trimming the inputs.

Just kidding. If that is a possibility, this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE title RLIKE '^[[=space=]]*[^[=space=]]+[[=space=]]*$'
```

Comment: One small doubt, If a single word with a space in the end like ``cat  ``, then?

Answer (score 1):

If a single word with a space in the end like 'cat '.

**Query**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(title VARCHAR(250));

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('cat ');
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('dog');
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('cat and dog');

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM title) NOT LIKE '% %';
```

**[Fiddle Demo 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e3e3e/6)**

---

If space in both start and end. Then,

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM title) NOT LIKE '% %';
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE TRIM(title) NOT LIKE '% %';
```

**[Fiddle Demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d868c/1)**

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that also works :P . Will fail for `" rat"` though. Why not simple `TRIM(title)`?

Comment: We can use simple `TRIM()`. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about using a regular expression to do the matching. I assume that by one word you mean that it should not have spaces in it. You can match this with the following expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE Title NOT REGEXPR '.* .*'
```

This should catch any title that has a space in it and exclude those from the results.